# Where can FOIA requests be found?

Tags: united-states, foia

United States federal (e.g. [FOIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States))) and state law allow people to request public records. The requests themselves are public record. Does any public or private entity maintain a database of those requests?

Comment: In E&W we have whatdotheyknow.com which is not quite what you're referring to, although close. And then many public authorities have public past-disclosures databases/portals that are somewhat closer to what you describe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't find a single repository of all FOIA requests, but you will find many large repositories of requests:

- [Muckrock](https://www.muckrock.com/foi/) permits users to submit FOIA requests basically anywhere, and then it publishes both the request and the resulting records to the Internet.
- [FOIA Online](https://foiaonline.gov/foiaonline/action/public/home) tracks requests for many federal agencies.
- [Department of Justice](https://www.justice.gov/oip/available-documents-oip) FOIA logs are published online.
- [SEC FOIA](https://www.sec.gov/foia/docs/foia-logs) logs are also published online.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example for Washington state under [RCW Ch. 42.56](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=42.56&full=true). First, you cannot request "all public records requests", because (RCW 42.56.080)

> (1) A public records request must be for identifiable records. A
> request for all or substantially all records prepared, owned, used, or
> retained by an agency is not a valid request for identifiable records
> under this chapter, provided that a request for all records regarding
> a particular topic or containing a particular keyword or name shall
> not be considered a request for all of an agency's records.

Second, there is no central agency that maintains all records – you would have to make a request of the State Patrol for all State Patrol records, the Department of Transportation for all Transportation requests, Department of Labor and Industries for their records, Ecology; Gambling; Liquor etc.

There are numerous private persons willing to take your money to make records requests, but they all seem to be "name-driven", that is, they get records about a specific person (pursuant to RCW 42.56.080). There is no Department of Central Records to whom you can make such a records request.

Answer (score 2):

The Department of Justice's Office of Information Policy has information about FOIA requests they've received, including some of the released documents: https://www.justice.gov/oip/available-documents-oip